# PHP Class Object inside method

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am having trouble using a mysqli object that was instantiated within one method of my class in a second method of the class. Can anyone help me to understand what I might be doing wrong? Here is what my two class methods look like:

```
function connect() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

    if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Successful';
    }

}

public function query($sql) {
    $this->sql = $sql;
    $mysqli->connect();
    $result = $mysqli->query($this->sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("$s (%s)\n", $row['name']);
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $result->free();

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

I think my trouble is making the instantiated object public.

****UPDATED: This is currently the entire class that I have and the script is dying when trying to execute a line within the query method:

```
$this->mysqli->connect();
```

---

```
class database {
    public $host = "host";
    public $user = "user";
    public $pass = "pw";
    public $db = "dbname";
    public $sql;
    private $mysqli;

    function __construct() {
        echo "new class object created";
        echo "<br><br>";
    }

    function connect() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        if($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo 'Successful';
        }

    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
        echo "test1";
        $this->mysqli->connect();
        echo "test2";
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($this->sql);
        echo "test3";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ("$s (%s)\n", $row['name']);
            echo "<br>";
        }

        $result->free();

        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

---

```
echo "test2"; does not execute.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're issue is variable scoping. You can't access it the way you want without specifying it `global`'ly.

You'd be better to stick to best practice and do something like this:

```
private $mysqli;

function connect() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

    if($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Successful';
    }

}
```

You notice how we defined it to `$this` (within the object). Now you'll be able to access it:

```
public function query($sql) {
    $this->sql = $sql;
    $this->connect();
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($this->sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("$s (%s)\n", $row['name']);
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $result->free();

    $this->mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fred, always got my back ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. I actually had it somewhat setup this way originally. I have now implemented the changes you suggested. I am still having trouble with it however. The script seems to die when the query function is called right after $this->mysqli->query($this->sql)

Comment: @NickGerrer That usually means it's failing somehow. Have you checked for any errors?

Comment: Not finding any errors via any logs. Updated my post above to display my entire class. The echo statement after $this->mysqli->query($this->sql) method call does not execute.

Comment: @darren - i will also note i got it to work using procedural style from the very beginning but no such luck in oop.

Comment: @NickGerrer turn on error reporting - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and also, does the `connect()` method print any error? Cause it might be failing there as your `echo '2';` is right after that method and there is an `exit()` call in there.

Comment: @darren - No failure or success printed from connect() method. If being executed correctly it should display something. Ill check out error reporting when i get back to my home computer. I had been playing around with this at work so havent had the ability to fully devote. I appreciate your help to this point. Ill let you know how i make out

Comment: @NickGerrer Sounds perfect, keep me up to date!

Comment: @NickGerrer SPOTTED THE ERROR: this `$this->mysqli->connect();` should be `$this->connect();`! I can't believe I typed that!

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes total sense. Ill test it out as soon as i can. Thanks again @darren

Answer (score 0):

A method is a function. Just like with any other function, variables that you declare inside the function cannot be accessed outside of that function.